# Apply java script / Jquery on page after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one page app which need to appear after user login.
The main page is hidden behind the login bar, and shows after user login success , using ajax call.
The problem is , after I reveal the content , which changed according to the user data, all the javascript functions and plugins doesn't work because the page is not in the DOM when the page load.
how can I run the script on the hidden page?

Thanks

Comment: Learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Don't run your code that installs event handlers UNTIL the content is in the DOM.  Put it all in a master function and call that master function AFTER you've put everything into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you mean `page is not in DOM`. If you are adding some dynamic content to your page after Ajax call, then inside success function apply all plugins again and all event listeners rewrite to `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function(){})`

Comment: Thanks,
So I need to apply on / live on each event ?

Comment: @user2221046 Edit your question and add jQuery script and HTML markup